How to make a llm remember previous runtime chats
I want my llm chatbot to remember previous conversations even after restarting the program. It is made with llama cpp python and langchain, it has conversation memory of the present chat but obviously doesn't have memory of the previous chat and that's what I need help in.
import threading
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough, RunnableLambda

def create_chain(system_prompt):
    model_path = ("dolphin-2_6-phi-2.Q4_K_M.gguf")

    llm = LlamaCpp(
            model_path=model_path,
            temperature=0,
            max_tokens=256,  # Reduced to fit within the context window
            top_p=1,
            verbose=False,
            streaming=False,  # Disable streaming for terminal interaction
            stop=["Human:"]
            )

    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
            ("system", system_prompt),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
            ("human", "{human_input}"),
            ("ai", ""),
        ])

    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history",

                                      return_messages=True)

    def save_memory(inputs_outputs):
        inputs = {"human": inputs_outputs["human"]}
        outputs = {"ai": inputs_outputs["ai"]}
        memory.save_context(inputs, outputs)

    def extract_response(chain_response):
        return chain_response["ai"]

    llm_chain = {
            "human_input": RunnablePassthrough(),
            "chat_history": (
                RunnableLambda(memory.load_memory_variables) |
                itemgetter("chat_history")
            )
        } | prompt | llm

    chain_with_memory = RunnablePassthrough() | {
                "human": RunnablePassthrough(),
                "ai": llm_chain
            } | {
                "save_memory": RunnableLambda(save_memory),
                "ai": itemgetter("ai")
            } | RunnableLambda(extract_response)
    return chain_with_memory

system_prompt = ("")
llm_chain = create_chain(system_prompt)

def chat():
    print("AI Chatbot (Type 'exit' to quit)\n")
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ").strip()
        if user_input.lower() == "exit":
            print("Exiting chat...")
            break

        if user_input:
            response = llm_chain.invoke(user_input)
            print(f"AI: {response}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chat()

I have no gpu 8gb ram and an i5 processor but my llm works on it fine. But it still requires that memory management updated.
